# "instance Show State where" doesn't compile

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

This is the State Monad code I am trying to figure out

```
data State a = State (Int -> (a, Int)) 
instance Monad State where
    return x = State (\c -> (x, c))     
    State m >>= f = State (\c ->
        case m c of { (a, acount) ->
            case f a of State b -> b acount})

getState = State (\c -> (c, c))
putState count = State (\_ -> ((), count))

instance Show State where  -- doesn't work
    show (State a) = show a   -- doesn't work
```

I am trying to make State as instance of Show so that I can see the action of `getState` and `putState count` on the ghci prompt.

Any tutorial or link to State Monad material would be nice too.

Comment: If you get compiler errors that you want solved, you should always put them in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Here's is a `Show` instance that can help see what's going on:

```
instance Show a => Show (State a) where
  show (State f) = show [show i ++ " => " ++ show (f i) | i <- [0..3]]
```

Then you can do:

```
*Main> getState
["0 => (0,0)","1 => (1,1)","2 => (2,2)","3 => (3,3)"]
*Main> putState 1
["0 => ((),1)","1 => ((),1)","2 => ((),1)","3 => ((),1)"]
```

Answer (score 5):

In Haskell, typeclasses classify only types of the same *kind*. Monad classifies types of kind `* -> *`, while Show classifies types of kind `*`. Your State type has kind `* -> *` which is why there isn't a problem with your `Monad` instance, but there *is* a problem with your `Show` instance. `State` is called a "type constructor" because it consumes a type in order to produce another type. Think of it sort of like function application at the type level. You can therefore apply a specific type and make instances of that:

```
instance Show (State Char) where
    show _ = "<< Some State >>"
```

Now, this isn't a very useful instance, try something like Sjoerd's suggestion to get a more meaningful Show instance. Notice that his version uses a *generic type* with a *constraint*.

```
instance (Show a) => Show (State a) where
    -- blah blah
```

The generic type is `a`, and the constraint is `(Show a) =>`, in other words, `a` itself must be an instance of `Show`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a great (and personally, my favorite) explanation of the State Monad:  [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#state).  (Also a great resource for learning Haskell in general).

You may have noticed that functions aren't part of the `Show` typeclass in Haskell.  And since `State` is basically just a `newtype` wrapper for functions of certain types, you can't make a (meaningful) `State` instance of `Show`.

---

Here's code using the State Monad from LYAH:

```
import Control.Monad.State -- first, import the state monad

pop :: State Stack Int  
pop = State $ \(x:xs) -> (x,xs)  

push :: Int -> State Stack ()  
push a = State $ \xs -> ((),a:xs)

stackManip :: State Stack Int  
stackManip = do  
    push 3  
    a <- pop  
    pop
```

And here's that code in action from `ghci`:

```
*Main> runState stackManip [1,2,3]
(1,[2,3])
```

The `fst` of the tuple is the result, and the `snd` of the tuple is the (modified) state.

Comment: Is there any visual way to show how the `getState` and `putState` works in the above code?

Comment: @Qin -- I'm not sure what you're asking -- but maybe you're looking for `runState`.  I've added an example.

Comment: typing runState says `Not in scope: 'runState'`  Do I have to import any module?