# Implementing Show for State

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Well this topic has been discusses before so I'm linking to it.

[Previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966956/instance-show-state-where-doesnt-compile)

So I'm sure it worked at the time, but time has changed :)

As a Haskell newbie making small steps this would take me one step further.
I've tried various solutions with various issues.

suggested solution

```
instance Show a => Show (State a) where
  show (State f) = show [show i ++ " => " ++ show (f i) | i <- [0..3]]
```

compiler reports.

```
 myfuncs.hs:31:11: error:
     Not in scope: data constructor ‘State’
     Perhaps you meant one of these:
       ‘StateT’ (imported from Control.Monad.State),
       variable ‘state’ (imported from Control.Monad.State)
    |
 31 |     show (State f) = show [show i ++ " => " ++ show (f i) | i <- [0..3]]
    |
```

I would appreciate an explantion of State state and StateT 
also understanding how :info State is to be interpreted.

```
type State s = StateT s Data.Functor.Identity.Identity :: * -> *
       -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy’
```

same question goes for info: state

```
class Monad m => MonadState s (m :: * -> *) | m -> s where
 ...
 state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> m a
       -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.State.Class’
```

Not sure I will understand the answer, however all help is appreciated.

Comment: You might also like [Where is the data constructor for `State`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24103108/791604).

Comment: The `State` in that question is not the type from the standard library, it's a custom type defined right there in the question. In particular, it is restricted to state values of type `Int`, which is why you can write a `Show` instance for it by sampling a bunch of numbers. This does not work for the real `State` type.

Comment: That said, you could do something similar for the real state type with an auxiliary `class SampleDomain a :: sampleDomain :: [a]` ; then `instance (SampleDomain s, Show s, Show a) => Show (State s a)`

Answer (score 4):

I have built the [universe-reverse-instances](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-reverse-instances) package for the purpose of showing functions on small domains (among other things). You can use it to create a `Show` instance for `State` this way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Universe
import Data.Universe.Instances.Reverse

deriving instance (Finite s, Show s, Show (m (a,s))) => Show (StateT s m a)
```

Try it out:

```
> modify not :: State Bool ()
StateT {runStateT = [(False,Identity ((),True)),(True,Identity ((),False))]}
```

It might be interesting to include something like this (and similar for `ReaderT`, etc.) in the `universe-reverse-instances` package. I'll have to think about a sane way to do that.

Explaining `State` and `StateT` from the ground up is probably a slightly larger task than would sensibly fit in an SO answer, but there are many tutorials floating around the web for this type.

Comment: May I use this opportunity to ask why you chose to show functions as _lists_? That's quite confusing. Using lambda-case syntax would be consistent.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Didn't wanna write a real parser for `Read`... I'm lazy! =P